# Identity with a product

Tags: exponentiation, products

I have some difficulties to show the following identity

$$\prod_{i=1}^m 2^{(n-i-1)/2}=2^{(nm/2)-m}$$

**My attempt:**

$$\prod_{i=1}^m 2^{\frac{n-i-1}{2}}\triangleq 2^k$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
k&\triangleq\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{n-i-1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n (n-i-1)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^m1-\sum_{i=1}^m i\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[(n-1)m-\frac{m(m+1)}{2}\right]\\
&=\frac{nm}{2}-\frac{m^2+3m}{4}
\end{aligned}$$

so my conclusion is,

$$\prod_{i=1}^m 2^{(n-i-1)/2}=2^{nm/2-(m^2+3m)/4}$$

Where am I wrong?

---

**Update:**

I have inferred the previous equality from the following equation
$$
\prod_{i<j}^m [(2\pi)^{1/2}]\prod_{i=1}^m\left\{2^{(n-i-1)/2}\Gamma\left[\frac{1}{2}(n-i+1)\right]\right\}=\pi^{m(m-1)/4}\prod_{i=1}^m \Gamma\left[\frac{1}{2}(n-i+1)\right]\cdot2^{mn/2-m}
$$

which is written at page 71 in *Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory* by Muirhead.

Comment: Second equality is wrong.

Comment: A lot easier to read and make sense of it if you take the logarithm base 2 of the expression before you start. I know that's sort of what you've done, but if you explicitly do that operation, then everything is then in full size display text rather than being the impossible-to-read superscript font.

Comment: Your work looks correct.  Where did you get the original RHS?

Comment: I'm studying the proof of theorem 2.1.15 of Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory by Muirhead. The equality is implicitly written on page 71.

Comment: The formula you are trying to prove is incorrect. Just try $m=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted the powers of $2$ arising from the first product:
$$\prod_{i<j}^m 2^{1/2} = 2^{\binom{m}{2}/2} = 2^{m(m-1)/4}$$

Comment: You're right. I forgot the power of 2 in the first product, I need to review my calculation in front of this fact. Thanks a lot. BTW, how did you get it the $n$ parameter? There is only $m$ as parameter in such product.

Comment: OK I think that's a typo, you have mistakenly write $m(n-1)/4$ instead of $m(m-1)/4$.

Comment: Yes, typo corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the bijectivity of $\log_2$ (logarithm base $2$), your identity is equivalent to

$$\sum_{i=1}^m \dfrac12(n-i-1) = \dfrac{nm}{2}-m$$

Let us transform its LHS:

$$\dfrac12 \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^m  n}_{nm}- \dfrac12\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^m( i+1)}_{\tfrac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2}-1} = \dfrac{nm}{2}-m$$

A problem: there is no agreement for the second terms in the LHS and RHS !

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. That's the same conclusion that I got it.